# Who was the speedster from the Flash/Supergirl crossover?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, supergirl-2015

Who was that speedster that had Supergirl's powers, in the Supergirl/Flash crossover?

Was he really a good guy or will he become Flash's next opponent?

Comment: “Was he really a good guy or will he become Flash's next opponent?” — It’s a bit difficult to tell unless we can get this time machine working to go watch all the remaining episodes.

Answer (score 4):

No "speedsters" visit Earth-1 during the crossover episode [Duet](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Duet) (S03E17).

Supergirl is brought to Earth-1 by two people:

[J'onn J'onzz](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/J%27onn_J%27onzz), AKA: The Martian Manhunter - a shapeshifting Martian who has enhanced strength, telepathy, and flight capabilities.

[image: Martian Manhunter]

[Mon-El](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Mon-El), the Daxamite, who has powers largely identical to Supergirl herself.

[image: Mon-El]

Both characters are on Team-Supergirl, and are highly unlikely to ever become villains on *The Flash*.

The [Music Meister](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Meister) also made an appearance during this episode. He also does not appear to be an inherent speedster, only demonstrating speed abilities while drawing energy from Barry.

[image]

At the end of the episode,

> Music Meister claims that he never meant to hurt the heroes - and that he was trying to help them in his own way.

Even Darren Criss has said that he does not see Music Meister as a villain. From [his interview with EW](http://ew.com/tv/2017/03/16/flash-supergirl-musical-crossover-darren-criss-music-meister/):

> A lot of people have been asking me, “What villain are you playing?” I’m like, “**He’s not really a villain, he’s more just kind of an a–hole.**” They let me run loose a little bit as far as being silly and goofy with the character, and I push it a little too far and they’re like, “Make sure to dial back a little bit,” because I’m trying to keep it in the tone of the world. But he’s definitely a goofy — a meister.

While there have been a few tiny references to Music Meister already, there has, to date, been no news of a recurring role for the character to become a villain or foil to the Flash.

Comment: I was not talking about them I was talking about that speedster who sent supergirl and flash in that imaginary world

Comment: @sgrmshrsm7 That's the Music Meister